# How to Link JavaScript and HTML using Eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eclipse, ide

I just finished Rock Paper Scissors exercise on codecademy and wanted to try save it on my Eclipse. The code was perfectly fine coded and it runs smoothly on the codecademy page. I then just simply copy everything and and have created .js workspace on Eclipse and paste it there.

My question is, how do I run/play it on eclipse? I do know I've to create html workspace as well and I already did, but I'm not sure what to put inside the html.

I'm not a full fledge programmer/web developer but I'd love be one someday. I've few knowledge about html learned from codecademy as well.

### If someone could show me how it can be linked between my JS code and html, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks

JS code:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
console.log("userChoice: " + userChoice);

var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "rock wins";
        } else {
        return "paper wins";
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "paper wins";
        } else {
        return "scissors wins";    
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "rock wins";    
        } else {
        return "scissors wins";    
        }
    } 
}; 
console.log(compare(userChoice,computerChoice));
```

---

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src = "myJSCode.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems already to be linked, but probably you are expecting a visual result in HTML - it's not happening because `console.log()` writes to the Browsers console, not to HTML.

Comment: yes I am expecting a visual result in html. or is it I can actually just use js only without html for a visual result on eclipse? i've no idea. please help. tq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the javascript file and the html file are in the same folder.

Or, if you want to store them in different folders you can just add the filepath like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "path/myJSCode.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is in the same folder. I just don't know how to make a visual result in eclipse showing the game I've coded. thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it in eclipse, since that is'nt a program that i use but  if you have a webserver installed on your machine (apache for example) you can host it there and then visit it on http://localhost:/     And whilst there you need to open the browsers console to view your little game, in most browsers the shortcut is: Ctrl+Shift + i